# What is the difference between "One vs Rest" and "One vs One" strategies in Multiclass classification in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have checked the wikipedia page but can't find the differences between them,Both seem to be converting multi classes into multiple linear classifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is about the strategy to split the data for training. Suppose you have N data-samples with C classes.

One-vs-One: Here, you pick 2 classes at a time, and train a two-class-classifier using samples from the *selected two classes only* (other samples are ignored in this step). You repeat this for all the two class combinations. So you end up with N(N-1)/2 classifiers. And while testing, you do voting among these classifiers.

One-vs-Rest: Here, you pick one class and train a two-class-classifier with the samples of the selected class on one side and all the other samples on the other side. Thus, you end up with N classifiers. While testing, you simply classify the sample as belonging to the class with maximum score among the N classifiers.

As an example, suppose we have a 3 class problem, with class labels c1, c2, and c3. And let samples be x1, x2, .... Let the classifiers be f1, f2, ....
So, suppose your training data is { {x1, c1}, {x2, c1}, {x3, c2}, {x4,c1}, {x5, c2}, {x6, c3}, {x7, c3} }.
Then:

One-vs-One:
f1: trained with the subset { {x1, c1}, {x2, c1}, {x3, c2}, {x4,c1}, {x5, c2} }, for classes c1 and c2
f2: trained with the subset { {x3, c2}, {x5, c2}, {x6, c3}, {x7, c3} }, for classes c2 and c3.
f3: trained with the subset { {x1, c1}, {x2, c1}, {x4,c1}, {x6, c3}, {x7, c3} }, for classes c2 and c3.

One-vs-Rest:
f1: trained with { {x1, c1}, {x2, c1}, {x3, ~c1}, {x4,c1}, {x5, ~c1}, {x6, ~c1}, {x7, ~c1} }, for class c1 and the rest (~c1, i.e, NOT c1).
f2: trained with { {x1, ~c2}, {x2, ~c2}, {x3, c2}, {x4, ~c2}, {x5, c2}, {x6, ~c2}, {x7, ~c2} }, for class c2 and the rest (~c2, i.e, NOT c2).
f3: trained with { {x1, ~c3}, {x2, ~c3}, {x3, ~c3}, {x4, ~c3}, {x5, ~c3}, {x6, c3}, {x7, c3} }, for class c3 and the rest (~c3, i.e, NOT c3).

Comment: What's the score in One vs Rest?Is it the number of positive results(+1) obtained in the linear classifier?

Comment: Score is the confidence of the classifier. For example, if you train a linear classifier, it could be the distance of the sample from the line. So the classifier with the largest score would win.

Comment: What's the point in having these strategies if you can use a natively multiclass model such as decision trees or neural nets?

Answer (score 0):

Like one-vs-rest, one-vs-one splits a multi-class classification dataset into binary classification problems. Unlike one-vs-rest which splits it into one binary dataset for each class, the one-vs-one approach splits the dataset into one dataset for each class versus every other class.

as per the eg let's suppose we have 3 classes A, B, C

in the one vs rest technique, we make a dataset like A and rest all, B and rest all, C and rest all.

for the one vs one we make a different possible pair like this
A and B
A and C
B and C

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).